# How can I export my ios7 app from Xcode 5 to an iphone 5

Tags: xcode, ios7

I have been attempting to make an app for a technology fair project, but cannot download my app onto the iphone I am going to test it on. I have about two weeks, so it would be excellent if your could reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Dear Jacob, Your question is not clear, elaborate precisely so we can understand what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to purchase an Apple developer license and register your devices UDID.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchase an Apple developer account, you are then able to run the application using an attached iPhone as a simulator.

First of all, register the device as UDID. More information here:

https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

Then, select your device as the simulator and run.

This will then move a copy of your application to your iPhone.